# functions vs. case (coding style)

Tags: elixir

I have the function `render_upvotes/1` which renders a string. I struggle to find the best way of representing it code wise. The following two versions have the same functionality. Which one is better coding style wise? Why? Is there an even better 3rd way of solving this?

### Version 1

```
def render_upvotes(number) do
  case {number} do
    {1} ->
      '1 upvote'
    {number} when is_integer(number) ->
      [Integer.to_string(number),' upvotes']
    _ ->
      []
  end
end
```

### Version 2

```
def render_upvotes(1) do
  '1 upvote'
end

def render_upvotes(number) when is_integer(number) do
  [Integer.to_string(number),' upvotes']
end

def render_upvotes(_) do
  []
end
```

Comment: I'd probably just use gettext to handle this kind of thing.

Comment: It's just an example. I'd like to know which way is the better way.

Comment: This is a rather hard question to answer as any answer given will primarily be opinion. Each person may have a different style preference. There also  is not a one size fits all answer. Someone may do multiple heads for this example, while another similar example they may prefer to use a case.

Comment: This is more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @wintermeyer Define "better".  Better in what sense?  Easier to read?  Faster execution?  Easier for maintenance?  This is exactly the definition of "opinion based" because the word better has almost no meaning without additional context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example could be simplified a bit by removing the unnecessary tuple:

```
def render_upvotes(number) do
  case number do
    1 ->
      '1 upvote'
    number when is_integer(number) ->
      [Integer.to_string(number),' upvotes']
    _ ->
      []
  end
end
```

After this change, both versions are essentially equivalent. When the function dispatcher looks for which function to execute, it will match the arguments provided in the function call against the patterns of your function definitions. Another way to think about this is, that there is already an implicit `case` statement during function dispatch, so why have two of those?

Apart from this very technical perspective, it appears more natural to me to break this up into multiple function clauses, as in your version 2. Having looked at a large amount of Elixir code so far, this also seems to be the accepted best practice in the Elixir community.

One thing that seems strange to me in your implementation is that you are trying to handle the case where a non-integer was passed to your function. In my opinion this should be considered a programmer mistake and should not be handled by the function. After all, you cannot return a meaningful response in this case. Although it may depend on your particular use case, just consider leaving it off.

Another side note regarding your choice of charlists (single quoted) instead of bitstrings (double quoted): in general, you should prefer bitstrings over charlists – unless you are writing code to interface with some erlang package that uses charlists. Charlists will also allow you to simplify your code with string interpolation. Also see http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html for more info on string types in Elixir.

All in all, here's how I would write the function:

```
def render_upvotes(1) do
  "1 upvote"
end

def render_upvotes(number) when is_integer(number) do
  "#{number} upvotes"
end
```

Comment: I did the IO Lists because of https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/elixir-and-io-lists-part-1-building-output-efficiently/. Is this a wrong way in a Phoenix environment?

Comment: IO lists != charlists. If you really need to optimize it, you can still use IO lists with bitstrings. In fact, you were already doing that since `Integer.to_string/1` returns a bitstring, not a charlist. I would personally not sacrifice readability for optimizations at such a small scale, though it is a good idea to build up strings with IO lists. In my experience this approach shines especially if the strings are large with repetitive content, or many static parts – which then only need to be allocated once. How much difference this makes for your app can only be found out with a benchmark.